# Installing PowershellGet module returns error

Tags: azure, powershell, powershell-5.0, azure-data-lake-gen2

I'm trying to follow the documentation on using Powershell to manage Azure Data Lake Gen 2 [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-directory-file-acl-powershell#install-powershell-modules) but I'm getting a warning and an error when trying to install the `PowerShellGet` module. Please see screen shot below.

[image]

If I ignore this and carry on with trying to run the next command below I get another error presumably because of the issue with installing `PowerShellGet` module above.

```
Install-Module az.storage -RequiredVersion 1.13.3-preview -Repository PSGallery -AllowClobber -AllowPrerelease -Force
```

I currently have Powershell 5.1 installed.

Comment: What's the error when you use `Install-Module az.storage -RequiredVersion 1.13.3-preview -Repository PSGallery -AllowClobber -AllowPrerelease -Force `?

Comment: Hi @JoyWang, I get the following error when I run that command https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/47343. The fix was to install PowerShellGet but get the error above.

Comment: Yeah I ran the command below to install the latest version and it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I can reproduce your issue with an old version of `PowerShellGet` module.

[image]

Actually the GA version of [`Az.Storage 1.14.0`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Az.Storage/1.14.0) which was released three days ago supports DataLake Gen2, so you could install it directly.

Use the command below, it will install the latest version `1.14.0` for you by default, no need to install `PowerShellGet` module.

```
Install-Module -Name Az.Storage -AllowClobber -Force
```

[image]